# Python - Calling a Procedure in a Windows DLL (by address, not by name)

Tags: python, function, dll, loadlibrary

I would like to know if it is possible (and if so, how) to call a routine from a DLL by the Proc address instead of by name - in Python.

Case in point: I am analyzing a malicious dll, and one of the routines I want to call is not exported (name to reference it by), however I do know the address to the base of the routine.

This is possible in C/C++ by casting the function pointer to a typedef'ed function prototype.

Is there a similar way to do this in Python?

If not, are there any concerns with modifying the export table of the dll, to make a known exported name map to the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify the export table, changing the base address of an already exported routine to my own routine.

This allowed me to execute the subroutine I was interested in via Python by using the exported name.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for the solution to get function by address in Python.
I still don't know how to do that, but I found an alternative approach to get unnamed function by its ordinal (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), like this:

```
dll = CDLL("mydll.dll")
myfunc = dll[32] # the 32-th function
```

Comment: Yes, but that still requires the routine to be an exported one.